# ontextchanged event problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does anyone know what is here wrong? Something with ontextchanged which i do not understand

> Description: An error occurred during
>   the compilation of a resource required
>   to service this request. Please review
>   the following specific error details
>   and modify your source code
>   appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1061:
>   'ASP.webcrawleradmin_rulesmanager_aspx'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'txtDynamic_TextChanged' and no
>   extension method
>   'txtDynamic_TextChanged' accepting a
>   first argument of type
>   'ASP.webcrawleradmin_rulesmanager_aspx'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dinamična vsebina">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDynamicValue" runat="server" 
            Text='<%#Eval("DynamicValue")%>' AutoPostBack="True" 
            ontextchanged="txtDynamicValue_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
protected void txtDynamicValue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
    RulesManagerPresenter.OnDynamicValueChanged(txt.Text, GetTagName(txt.NamingContainer), QueryStringRuleGroup);

    presenter.OnLoadTagsAndValues4Presentation(ConnectionString);*/
}
```

EDIT:

solved. VS 2010 problem. Changing debug from x86 to any CPU solve my problem if anyone else has this problems...

Comment: This error simply means that you try to call a method that does not exist (`txtDynamic_TextChanged`). Are you sure your code doesn't contain a reference to it?

Answer (score 1):

Does your event handler need to be public?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.ontextchanged.aspx), the handler has only one argument which is the EventArgs.

So, change the function signature to:

```
protected void txtDynamicValue_TextChanged(EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting `<%` and `%>` around the code like so:

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dinamična vsebina">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDynamicValue" runat="server"
                 Text='<%#Eval("DynamicValue")%>' AutoPostBack="True"
                 ontextchanged="txtDynamicValue_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <%protected void txtDynamicValue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
        RulesManagerPresenter.OnDynamicValueChanged(txt.Text, GetTagName(txt.NamingContainer), QueryStringRuleGroup);
        presenter.OnLoadTagsAndValues4Presentation(ConnectionString);*/
    }%>
```

You could also have [a look at this](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_textbox.asp) which does something very similar in VB

Comment: I assumed that was just a cut sample from a code behind and wasn't totally confident that my answer was correct. You could be right.

Comment: @BenCr i was assuming that it was all in the .aspx file